# how can calculate row in table by javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my Code :

```
<html>

  <body>
    <table id="my Table">


      <tbody>

        <tr>
```

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

```
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['ItemQTY']; ?>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="total Column">
          <td class="tota Column">Total:</td>

        </tr>



      </tbody>

    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want to make the last row in the table sum of ItemQTY

this java to search in the table

```
            function myFunction() {
              // Declare variables 

              var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
              input = document.getElementById("myInput");
              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
              table = document.getElementById("myTable");
              tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

              // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
              for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                  } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                  }
                } 
              }
            }
```

but this script not calculate total qty
how can add calculate row with this code

Comment: post your code, what you have done so far!

Comment: calculate the total via function and then substitute the value dynamically adding a new tr

Comment: Can You explain ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sum up the values in `PHP` and store it in variable. Then just print it in Total row.

```
$totalQty = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $totalQty += $row['ItemQTY'];
    ?>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['ItemQTY']; ?>
    </td>
<?php
} ?>

<tr class="total Column">
      <td class="tota Column">Total: <?php echo $totalQty;?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have java script to filter this table but when i filter $totalQty not change

Comment: this my java script

Comment: Can you post JavaScript code in your question and explain what you need?

Comment: i add the java script

Comment: JS code looks good. Issue is with `id` attribute in `HTML`. Replace `<table id="my Table">` with `<table id="myTable">`. Remove space.

Answer (score -1):

If your HTML page contains only one table then you can get count of `<tr>` tags.

You will get total rows in the table then subtract the last row ( i.e. 1 row for showing total) from your total count. You can get count of `<tr>` tag in JavaScript as follows:

```
var rowCount = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length - 1;
```